I have created a CustomUser model and it shows up in base app and not under Authorization and Authentication
I have created a custom User Model which is inside the base app and the custom User Model shows up in base app in the admin site instead of authorization and authentication. Why is it coming under it?
Here is my models.py:
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser
from .managers import CustomManager
# Create your models here.


class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50,default='Yet to be updated...')
    email = models.EmailField('email_address', unique=True)
    USN = models.CharField(max_length=10, default='Yet to be updated...')
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    # updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    # created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = CustomManager()

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_superuser
    
    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return self.is_superuser

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

Here is my managers.py:
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import BaseUserManager

class CustomManager(BaseUserManager):

    def create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("Email is must")
        
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)

        user.set_password(password)

        user.save()

        return user
    
    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_active', True)

        return self.create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

Here is my admin.py:
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import CustomUser
# Register your models here.


admin.site.register(CustomUser)

Why is the custom User not under Authorization and Authentication and how can I add it there?

